# order() not doing its job

Tags: r, dataframe

This is driving me nuts. I am trying to sort a data frame by the first row in ascendinging order using the order function. Below a minimal example:

```
values <- c(11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)

labels <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K")

df <- data.frame(rbind(values,labels))

newdf <- df[,with(df,order(df[1,]))]

print(newdf)
```

I have also tried this with

```
newdf <- df[,order(df[1,])]
```

Here is the output I'm getting

```
        X11 X2 X1 X10 X9 X8 X7 X6 X5 X4 X3
values   1 10 11   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
labels   K  B  A   J  I  H  G  F  E  D  C
```

Which is clearly wrong! So what is going on here?

Comment: what is `claims`

Comment: All your variables are "character", so the order is correct in alphanumeric ordering - `"1","10","11","2","3"...` all the 1's, all the 2's etc etc.

Comment: Any reason you're not doing this as columns instead of rows? `df <- data.frame(values, labels); df[order(df$values),]`

Comment: and in fact, they are factors. beyond that. If you actually do the order correctly, you'll see it ends up ordering it according to the labels.

Comment: ‘order’ is doing exactly what you told it to do. Learn to use as.character when attempting to order factor levels.

Comment: @42 oddly enough, that's what usually happens :)

Comment: Rows is more convenient for my application. I don't want it ordered according to labels, won't work for my problem.

Comment: Your code (and the text of your question) implied ordering of columns. And you have apparently not comprehended that these are factor variables and they don't behave the way you imagined. Look at the output of `rbind(values,labels)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an odd way to structure your data in R, so it will cause headaches, but you can make it work. See @thelatemail 's comment re: columns vs rows. To make this work in your case, do:

```
values <- c(11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
labels <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K")
df <- data.frame(rbind(values,labels), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
newdf <- df[order(as.numeric(df["values",]))]
newdf
#        X11 X10 X9 X8 X7 X6 X5 X4 X3 X2 X1
# values   1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
# labels   K   J  I  H  G  F  E  D  C  B  A
```

Note, in particular, `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you create the data frame.

Remember, data.frames are lists, and each element of the list is a vector (possibly a list, but typically an atomic vector, especially if constructed in a standard way) of the same length. The individual elements of the data frame are columns. Rows are just the nested elements with the same index value. This makes it much easier to work with a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(values = values, labels = labels)
df[order(df$values),]
#    values labels
# 11      1      K
# 10      2      J
# 9       3      I
# 8       4      H
# 7       5      G
# 6       6      F
# 5       7      E
# 4       8      D
# 3       9      C
# 2      10      B
# 1      11      A
```

Here you don't have to worry at all about whether your numbers are going to be coerced to characters and/or factors when you line them up with another vector that's character. In this example, whether or not `labels` was a factor had no impact on `values`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. I need it as rows, the application is not statistical, I am pre-sorting becaue another package requires it in this format. Otherwise, yes I agree columns would be better.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work (I spoke to soon). This method turned out not be reliable. 
What I ended up doing which did work was doing it as columns following Dan's suggestion, as follows:

    df <- data.frame(values = values, names = names)
    newdf <- df[order(df$values),]

Then unlisting the values
    values <- c(unlist(newdf["values"]))

and then the names

    names <- c(as.character(newdf["names"]$names))

to get them into the required format. Thanks to everyone for their comments and assitance, especially Dan.